# Cannot inject the application context with hilt dependency inject

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

This is the module Class

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {


    @Provides
    fun getAppPreferences(
        @ApplicationContext context: ApplicationContext,
        @Named("appName") appName: String
    ):SharedPreferences {
        return (context as Context).getSharedPreferences(appName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    }


    @Provides
    @Named("URL")
    fun getBaseUrl(): String {
        return AppConstants.BASE_URL
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun getApiService(
        client: OkHttpClient, @Named("URL") baseURL: String,
        factory: GsonConverterFactory
    ): ApiInterface {

        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseURL)
            .addConverterFactory(factory)
            .client(client)
            .build()
            .create(ApiInterface::class.java)

    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun getClient(sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences): OkHttpClient {

        val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        return OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .addInterceptor { chain ->
                val requestBuilder = chain.request().newBuilder()
                val token = ProjectUtil.getApiTokenBearer(sharedPreferences)
                token?.apply {
                    requestBuilder.addHeader("Authorization", token)
                }
                chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build())
            }
            .connectTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()

    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun getConvertorFactory(): GsonConverterFactory {

        val gson = GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create()
        return GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)

    }

    @Provides
    @Named("appName")
    fun getAppName() = "CarApplication"

}
```

This is my viewmodel constructor

```
@HiltViewModel
class HomeFragmentViewModel @Inject constructor(
    val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences,
    private val apiService: ApiInterface
) : ViewModel() {

    private lateinit var createEquriumDialog: Dialog

    //    val progress_dialog = MyOwnProgressDialog(context)
    var showAquariumRv: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData()
    var equariumList: ListUserAquariumResponse? = null
    val goToActivityIntent: MutableLiveData<Intent> = MutableLiveData()
    val progress: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData()
    val showMessage: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
}
```

**i get this error when i run the application which i think donot Inject the application context required in the Module any help would be apreciated**

C:\XYZ\XYZ\AndroidStudioProjects\CarAndroid\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\com\sw\car\baseclasses\CarApp_HiltComponents.java:128: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] @dagger.hilt.android.qualifiers.ApplicationContext dagger.hilt.android.qualifiers.ApplicationContext cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract static class SingletonC implements DaluaApp_GeneratedInjector,
^
@dagger.hilt.android.qualifiers.ApplicationContext dagger.hilt.android.qualifiers.ApplicationContext is injected at
com.sw.car.di.modules.AppModule.getAppPreferences(context, �)
android.content.SharedPreferences is injected at
com.sw.car.ui.home.fragments.home.HomeFragmentViewModel(sharedPreferences, �)
com.sw.car.ui.home.fragments.home.HomeFragmentViewModel is injected at
com.sw.car.ui.home.fragments.home.HomeFragmentViewModel_HiltModules.BindsModule.binds(vm)
@dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelMap java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is requested at
dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.ViewModelFactoriesEntryPoint.getHiltViewModelMap() [com.devstudio.dalua.baseclasses.CarApp_HiltComponents.SingletonC ? com.devstudio.dalua.baseclasses.CarApp_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC ? com.devstudio.dalua.baseclasses.CarApp_HiltComponents.ViewModelC]

Answer (score 3):

It should be `@ApplicationContext context: Context,`

`ApplicationContext` is an annotation